# Invalid characters in XML tag name

Tags: php, xml, dom

We have a huge database where users can create custom fields. Every UTF-8 character is allowed in their name. Until a few weeks ago, when they export their data in XML, only invalid characters that users had in their tables were slash `/` and whitespace  characters, and we replaced them with underscores.

Now I see that some users who need an export in XML are using in their field names `*`, `!`... So if their field name instead `valid_name` is named for example `invalid*name!`, this script will break.

Part of code used for defining tag name:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$elementName = is_numeric($key) ? (string)$name : (string)$key;
$elementName = str_replace(array('/', ' '), '_', trim($elementName));

$node = $doc->createElement($elementName); // here I get error "invalid character name"
```

Sample of valid XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rows total="621" page="1">
    <row>
        <valid_name>60E49542D19D16EDB633A40</valid_name>
    ....
```

I don't need for users to see in their element name `!`, `*`... I need to know what are characters that aren't allowed to be in element name, And I will replace them probably with an underscore, I am opened also if you have better proposition instead of replacing them with an underscore.

Comment: `<customerDefinedField name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($elementName); ?>">` might be sensible.

Comment: Seems like an awfully complicated scheme - why not just have `<row><item><name>the users name</name></item></row>`. Would save you a world of trouble with characters which are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Quentin suggest the better way. Using dynamic node names mean that you can not define an XSD/Schema, your XML files will be wellformed only. You will not be able to make full use of validators. So a `<field name="..."/>` is a better solution from a machine readability and maintenance point of view.

However, NCNames (non-colonized names) allow for quite a lot characters. Here is what I implemented in my library for converting JSON.

`$nameStartChar` defines letters and several Unicode ranges. `$nameChar` adds some more characters to that definition (like the digits).

The first RegExp removes any character that is NOT a name char. The second removes any starting character that is NOT defined in `$nameStartChar`. If the result is empty it will return a default name.

```
function normalizeString(string $string, string $default = '_'): string {
    $nameStartChar =
      'A-Z_a-z'.
      '\\x{C0}-\\x{D6}\\x{D8}-\\x{F6}\\x{F8}-\\x{2FF}\\x{370}-\\x{37D}'.
      '\\x{37F}-\\x{1FFF}\\x{200C}-\\x{200D}\\x{2070}-\\x{218F}'.
      '\\x{2C00}-\\x{2FEF}\\x{3001}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}'.
      '\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFFD}\\x{10000}-\\x{EFFFF}';
    $nameChar =
      $nameStartChar.
      '\\.\\d\\x{B7}\\x{300}-\\x{36F}\\x{203F}-\\x{2040}';
    $result = \preg_replace(
      [
        '([^'.$nameChar.'-]+)u',
        '(^[^'.$nameStartChar.']+)u',
      ],
      '',
      $string
    );
    return empty($result) ? $default : $result;
}
```

An qualified XML node name can consist of two NC names separated by ':'. The first part would be the namespace prefix.

```
$examples = [
  '123foo', 
  'foo123', 
  '  foo  ', 
  '  ', 
  'foo:bar', 
  'foo-bar'
];

foreach ($examples as $example) {
    var_dump(normalizeString($example));
}
```

Output:

```
string(3) "foo"
string(6) "foo123"
string(3) "foo"
string(1) "_"
string(6) "foobar"
string(7) "foo-bar"
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) to decode the names. The output should be okay as field names and you can encode back if you need to. Replacing by underscore would make a reverse way impossible.

---

Edit: 
I was dramatically wrong, it's not that easy. Those two funtions should do the trick:

```php
function tag_encode(string $string): string {

    return 'tag_' . str_replace("%", "_", rawurlencode($string));
}


function tag_decode(string $string): string {

    return rawurldecode(str_replace("_", "%", substr($string, 4)));
}
```

- only keep ascii-characters in the name
- avoid beginning with underscore or number.

Comment: You can't have a `%` character (which is the URL escape character) in an XML tag name.

Comment: You've also confused encoding and decoding.